# Display Full-Page Overlay on Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to display a full-page overlay on page load, with the ability to dismiss the overlay by clicking an X to close. So the overlay displays by default when the page loads and then if it is dismissed then the rest of the website (code not included here) displays.

I've tried the below, not sure why it is not working though:

```js
function openNav() { 
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 36px;
 color: #818181;
 display: block;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus { color: #f1f1f1; }
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Something</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing the `width: 0` in the `.overlay` css - I would add `right: 0` instead :)

Comment: Yip, that worked like a dream. Thanks, @Teknotica

Comment: Glad to hear! You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Kindly Replace ".overlay" css with this:

.overlay {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For making the overlay to be full screen, depending upon the resolution, you can change the width and height properties from px to vh and vw.
For example:

```
.overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about the screen resolution. Fits perfectly with any type of screens.